# Forward declare a templated typedef

Tags: c++, boost, forward-declaration

In my public header, I am trying to add a pointer to an object which is only defined privately.  Normally that would be simple.  I just forward-declare.  However, the object is a bit complicated and I'm not sure how to forward declare it.

public.h:

```
#include <memory>
class StateMachine; // This forward declaration doesn't work

class MyClass {
    std::unique_ptr<StateMachine> sm_;
public:
    MyClass();
}
```

public.cpp

```
#include <public.h>
#include "statemachine.h" //StateMachine declared in full here
MyClass::MyClass 
  : obj_(std::make_unique<StateMachine>(*this)) 
{ 
}
```

statemachine.h:

```
#include <boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp>
#include <boost/msm/front/state_machine.hpp>
class MyClass; 

struct _StateMachine : public boost::msm::front::state_machine_def<_StateMachine>
{
    MyClass parent_;
public:
    _StateMachine(MyClass& p_parent);
};

typedef boost::msm::back::state_machine<_StateMachine> StateMachine;
```

where `boost::msm::back::state_machine` is defined as:

```
template <
      class A0
    , class A1 = parameter::void_
    , class A2 = parameter::void_
    , class A3 = parameter::void_
    , class A4 = parameter::void_
>
class state_machine { ... };
```

---

Here are some of the forward-declarations I've tried and their error messages (g++)

```
class StateMachine;
```

> error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef class boost::msm::back::state_machine<_StateMachine> StateMachine’

```
namespace boost{ namespace msm { namespace back { class state_machine; }}}
typedef boost::msm::back::state_machine StateMachine;
```

> error: ‘boost::msm::back::state_machine’ is not a template

```
namespace boost{ namespace msm { namespace back { template <class T> class state_machine; }}}
class _StateMachine;
typedef boost::msm::state_machine<_StateMachine> StateMachine;
```

> error: wrong number of template arguments (5, should be 1)

```
namespace boost{ namespace msm { namespace back { template<class T0, class T1, class T2, class T3, class T4> class state_machine; }}}
class _StateMachine;
typedef boost::msm::back::state_machine<_StateMachine> StateMachine;
```

> error: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 5)

```
namespace boost{ namespace msm { namespace back { template<class T0, class T1, class T2, class T3, class T4> class state_machine; }}}
class _StateMachine;
class Void;
typedef boost::msm::back::state_machine<_StateMachine, Void, Void, Void, Void> StateMachine;
```

> error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef class boost::msm::back::state_machine<_StateMachine> StateMachine’

Comment: It's impossible to forward-declare a type alias.

Comment: On a side note, identifiers beginning with underscore and an uppercase letter are reserved for the implementation. Use different names.

Comment: So I should probably use a `p_impl` design pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really don't want to include `boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp`, then you need to forward-declare `state_machine` and use it correctly.

Your attempt fails because `T1`, `T2`, `T3`, and `T4` are not given a type when instantiated.

```
namespace boost{ namespace msm { namespace back { template<class T0, class T1, class T2, class T3, class T4> class state_machine; }}}
class _StateMachine;
typedef boost::msm::back::state_machine<
    _StateMachine
    /* need types here, we don't know there are default ones defined later */
> StateMachine;
```

Your attempt with `class Void;` fails because `Void` is not `parameter::void_`, so the two typedefs are different.

Note before the solution: in C++, you should probably use `using` instead of `typedef`. Also, in C++17, you can do `namespace boost::msm::back { ... }`.

The solution is to forward declare `parameter::void_` as well and use it in the alias definition.

```
namespace boost::msm::back {
namespace parameter {
    // careful, this might be in a different namespace if there is a using namespace somewhere.
    class void_;
}
template<class T0, class T1, class T2, class T3, class T4> class state_machine;
}

class _StateMachine;
using StateMachine = boost::msm::back::state_machine<
    _StateMachine,
    boost::msm::back::parameter::void_,
    boost::msm::back::parameter::void_,
    boost::msm::back::parameter::void_,
    boost::msm::back::parameter::void_
>;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5bPeYY9Tr)

Unfortunately, you cannot provide `T1` through `T4` with default types because you cannot have multiple declarations of the default parts of template parameter lists, even if they match.

I don't see any other solution than this or including the boost header.